# Oracle SQL correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

I have the following query to show me the Count of rows of a given base_objectid:

```
Select Count(*) 
from 
(
select di.id, di.archkey, dc.mimetype, dc.film, dc.blip, dc.originalfilename, stp.id as baseID, null as Volume, stp.path as Dateiname_org, stp.basepath as Pfad, stp.filelength as Dateilaenge
, 1 as "Dateinummer", dc.idx
from 
doc_instance di 
, doc_content dc 
, sto_hydstorageplace stp 
where 
di.baseobjectid = :base_objectid
and stp.archivekey = di.archkey 
and di.id = dc.docinstanceid (+) 
and stp.imagenr = dc.idx
union 
select di.id, di.archkey, dc.mimetype, dc.film, dc.blip, dc.originalfilename, stf.id as baseID, stf.volume as Volume, stf.filename as Dateiname_org, stol.confvalue as Pfad, stf.filesize as Dateilaenge 
, stf.fileno as "Dateinummer", dc.idx 
from 
doc_instance di 
, doc_content dc
, sto_storagefileentry stf 
, sto_storagelevelconf stc 
, sto_storagelevelconfentry stol 
where
di.baseobjectid = :base_objectid 
and stf.archkey = di.archkey 
and stf.storagelevel = stc.storagelevel
and stc.id = stol.storagelevel 
and stol.confkey = 'FILEARCHIVE' 
and di.id = dc.docinstanceid (+) 
and stf.fileno-1 = dc.idx
) temp 
order by archkey, idx
```

Now I want to show me the Count of rows belonging to all base_objectids of another table, so the above query have to execute for every specific value of base_objectid. I assume that I have to make the above query to a subquery, but all my Trials fail.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you just need to change the `select` to:

```
select base_objectid, count(*)
```

Add a `group by` before the `order by`:

```
group by base_objectid
```

and remove any conditions restricting the output.

But it is hard to tell.  Your query is basically unintelligible because:

- You are using old-style `join` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *ALways* use explicit `join` syntax.
- Even worse, you are using outer joins with `(+)`, which even Oracle doesn't recommend any more.
- You have no indentation to help others understand the query.